# mysql_query Issue - Syntax error

Tags: php, mysql, sql, insert

I'm currently building a web form which has several drop down menus and I want to submit these into a SQL database through PHP.

I have little PHP knowledge but no better way to learn than doing it! I'm following this guide to post data back to my db - [Link](http://teamtutorials.com/web-development-tutorials/php-tutorials/inserting-data-into-a-mysql-database-using-php)

My code is:

```
$CLI = $_POST['CLI'];
$Environment = $_POST['Environment'];
$Type = $_POST['Type'];
$Fault = $_POST['Fault'];

$query="INSERT INTO testtable (cli, env, type, fault)VALUES ('$CLI', '$Environment', '$Type', '$Fault')"

mysql_query($query) or die (mysql_error());

echo "Database Updated With: ".$CLI";
```

When I'm editting this code I'm getting a syntax error on the mysql_query line and the echo line. I've uploaded this to my server however it goes to the php update page then doesnt post the data back to the db.

Can someone help please? I can't find any simple answers to fix it!

Thanks

Comment: What's the syntax error you're getting?

Comment: Can you do this: `echo $query;` before executing it.

Comment: Dreamweaver just points out I have a syntax error on lines:mysql_query($query) or die (mysql_error());

echo "Database Updated With: ".$CLI";

Comment: 1. you are asking to be hacked that way!
2. if you are getting a syntax error why don't you post the error?!
also check if all the fields you listed exist in your db table and things like that.

Comment: Technically, this is a PHP syntax error, and has nothing to do with MySQL, except the error occuring on a mysql-related line of code.

Comment: Please do not use `mysql_query` in new applications. This interface is being phased out because of serious problems with [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/php) as you've demonstrated in your simple example. If any of these values contain `'` then your query will not work. You should be using `mysqli` or PDO and placeholders to do this correctly under all circumstances.

Comment: I've added to my answer so you can see what @SparK is talking about.

Comment: Ok, thanks egrunin i'll have a read up on mysqli or PDO to replace the mysql_query. Do you know any good guides which will show me how to insert data using these?

Answer (score 4):

You need a semicolon at the end of the mysql line (after the last quote).

Probably you need a space before `VALUES`.

You have an extra `"` at the end of the last line.

In other words:

```
$query="INSERT INTO testtable (cli, env, type, fault) VALUES ('$CLI', '$Environment', '$Type', '$Fault')";

mysql_query($query) or die (mysql_error());

echo "Database Updated With: ".$CLI;
```

**NOTE:**

As was mentioned in a comment, if someone invokes the page passing this:

```
&Type=','');+DROP+TABLE+testtable;+--
```

...it will delete your data! Please read up on "Sql injection attacks" before it's too late.

Comment: assembling the query that way he is ought to be hacked soon, isn't he?

Comment: Thanks so much egrunin, that's sorted it :) I had too many "'s.

Comment: @user1634278 - glad to be of help, I've added more to address SparK's very important point.

Answer (score 1):

Please revise your code. You miss ; after `$query=...`, and you have extra `"` in the last line.

Answer (score 1):

You're missing a semicolon at the end of the line:

```
$query="INSERT INTO testtable (cli, env, type, fault)VALUES ('$CLI', '$Environment', '$Type', '$Fault')"
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to connect to your DB using `mysql_connect()` first before running `mysql_query()`.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php

Answer (score 0):

You don't have a semicolon at the end of the `$query="INSERT...` line and you have an extra double quote before the semicolon on the last line.

The PHP errors that are issue should, point this out to you pretty clearly.